# programs launched from docky are in different language

Tags: unity, language-support, docky

my system's language is turkish, so when I launch a program using a terminal or unity, the launched programs are -as one would expect- in turkish. However if I launch the same program from Docky, everything's in english.

I believe it was caused by me as I launch Docky using `env LC_ALL=C docky`, which causes it to run in default language, english. Unfortunately, I had to use that command, otherwise docky wouldn't launch at all due to some silly error caused by turkish characters.

My question is, is there any way to make Docky run in English but make the programs it launches run in my system's language?

EDIT:

the error that forced me to use `env LC_ALL=C docky`: *[SystemService] Could not initialize power manager dbus: 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.MatchRuleInvalid: Unknown key "ınterface" in match rule'*

please note: it's *ınterface*, not *interface*. first one is coded in UTF-8 and the other is in ASCII.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Some silly error caused by turkish characters" rings a bell here. ;-) Has it possibly something to do with [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/818770)?

This is just a guess, but what if you launch Docky like this:

```
LC_CTYPE=C docky
```

instead of using LC_ALL, which changes everything.

*Edit:*

I installed Docky and played around and ended up with this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=tr_TR.UTF-8 docky
```

Comment: I do believe it has something to do with that bug, but your suggestion did not fix my problem. Now docky gives an error at start: **[SystemService] Could not initialize power manager dbus: 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.MatchRuleInvalid: Unknown key "?nterface" in match rule'** when i just type `docky` in a terminal, i get the same error with `ınterface` instead of `?nterface`

Comment: @AlbinoPolarBear: I just edited my answer and added a solution that I think does what you want. It's indeed a workaround, and I'd suggest that you file a Docky bug report.

Comment: oops! Apparently not everyting is working. While docky can launch nautilus or ubuntu software center in turkish, some other apps like ubuntu tweak or system settings are still in english when launched by docky.

Comment: @AlbinoPolarBear: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Still an improvement, right? ;-)

Comment: oops #2! I forgot to give you a feedback on my latest situation. After a lot of reboots(I'm working to fix a lot worse problem right now that's why I forgot the feedback) I noticed that those random english apps all returned to turkish somehow... It seems that your workaround really worked it around after all. I also filed a bug report with the required info about turkish alphabet.

Comment: @AlbinoPolarBear: Great, and nice work with the bug report!